# How to use custom templates in gii (using Yii 2)

Tags: php, yii2, gii

I'm trying to find a way to use custom Gii templates for Yii 2, but looking at the [missing documentation in the docs](http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2docs/guide-gii.html#creating-your-own-templates), I assume it's not possible yet?
Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Copy ie. the crud generator templates from `gii/generators/crud/templates` to your application `app/templates/mycrud`.

Then define the templates in your config:

```
$config['modules']['gii'] = [
    'class'      => 'yii\gii\Module',
    'generators' => [
        'crud'   => [
            'class'     => 'yii\gii\generators\crud\Generator',
            'templates' => ['mycrud' => '@app/templates/mycrud']
        ]
    ]
];
```

Until the documentation is finished you may also have a look at my [Gii extension](http://github.com/schmunk42/yii2-giiant) how to create a custom generator and templates.